# Can I listen to Bluetooth Disconect with Flutter FlutterBlue?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm building a Flutter app where I need to listen for a certain Bluetooth device disconection.
I mean, I need some kind of callback when the bluetooth disconnects.

The app will run on both iOS and Android, and I have barely no idea of iOS programming, so I was looking for a flutter library able to do that.

My question is if FlutterBlue would be able to manage this behaviour, or if there is any alternative? I've been reading all examples and code I've found, but couldn't find anything near.

Also I've looked into the code and I've seen that you can listen to Bluetooth Characteristics changes, but I don't know if there is any Characteristic that would provide me that info, or if I even should bother about Characteristics.

The idea is to detect when you connect and disconnect from a bluetooth Handsfree, if that info matters.

Any help would be really apreciated!
Thank you all :)